# Compare first line from text file with others to see difference in time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have as a target first line from text file, then I try to compare the same line and all others from the text file to see what is the difference. I never get correct answer and I can't figure out where is my mistake in calculation. Some time gives me wrong answer for hours like in the 3rd row ( I get 13 hours difference and not 14).

```
def time_compare_gen(time_list , target):
    listReturn = []
    hour = 0 
    min = 0
    for tup in time_list:
        tuphour = int(tup[0])
        tupmin = int(tup[1])
        tarhour = int(target[0])
        tarmin = int(target[1])
        if tup[2] == target[2]:
            if tupmin > tarmin:
                if tuphour < tarhour:
                    tuphour += 24
            else:
                if tuphour > tarhour:
                    tuphour -= 1
                    tupmin += 60
                elif tuphour == tarhour and tupmin == tarmin:
                    tuphour = tuphour
                    tupmin = tupmin
                else:
                    tuphour += 23
                    tupmin += 60
        else:
            tuphour += 12
            if tupmin < tarmin:
                tuphour -= 1
                tupmin += 60
        hour = tuphour - tarhour
        min = tupmin - tarmin
        tupleReturn = (hour,min)
        listReturn.append(tupleReturn)
    return listReturn
```

My main:

```
with open("D:\\test.txt", "r") as file:
    target = file.readline()
    for last_line in file:
        pass
    
a=(target.replace(':', ' ').split())
tartuple= tuple(a)

TimeList = create_time_list("D:\\test.txt")
DiffList = time_compare_gen(TimeList,tartuple)
print ("{:<24} {:<20} {:<10}".format('Time Tuple', 'Diffrence', ' '))

for a,b in zip(TimeList , DiffList):
    if b[0] != 0 and b[1] != 0:
        timeval = str(a)
        diff = str(b)
        diffstr = str(b[0]) + " hours and " + str(b[1]) + " minutes in future"
        print ("{:<24} {:<20} {:<10}".format(timeval , diff , diffstr))
    else:
        print ("{:<24} {:<20} {:<10}".format(str(a) , str(b) , "Now"))
```

Output:

```
    Time Tuple               Diffrence                      
('2', '12', 'PM')        (0, 0)               Now       
('8', '23', 'PM')        (6, 11)              6 hours and 11 minutes in future
('4', '03', 'AM')        (13, 51)             13 hours and 51 minutes in future
('1', '34', 'AM')        (11, 22)             11 hours and 22 minutes in future
('3', '48', 'PM')        (1, 36)              1 hours and 36 minutes in future
('4', '13', 'AM')        (14, 1)              14 hours and 1 minutes in future
('1', '09', 'AM')        (10, 57)             10 hours and 57 minutes in future
('3', '12', 'PM')        (0, 60)              0 hours and 60 minutes in future
('4', '10', 'PM')        (1, 58)              1 hours and 58 minutes in future
```

Correct output should be like this :

```
    Time Tuple               Diffrence                      
('2', '12', 'PM')        (0, 0)               Now       
('8', '23', 'PM')        (6, 11)              6 hours and 11 minutes in future
('4', '03', 'AM')        (13, 51)             14 hours and 51 minutes in future
('1', '34', 'AM')        (11, 22)             11 hours and 22 minutes in future
('3', '48', 'PM')        (1, 36)              1 hours and 36 minutes in future
('4', '13', 'AM')        (14, 1)              14 hours and 1 minutes in future
('1', '09', 'AM')        (10, 57)             11 hours and 57 minutes in future
('3', '12', 'PM')        (0, 60)              0 hours and 60 minutes in future
('4', '10', 'PM')        (1, 58)              2 hours and 58 minutes in future
```

So as you see some times I get wrong calculations for hours.

Comment: What would be the correct output in this example?

Comment: [('2', '12', 'PM')        (0, 0)               Now]
[('8', '23', 'PM')        (4, 11)              4 hours and 11 minutes in future]
[('4', '03', 'AM')        (14, 51)             14 hours and 51 minutes in future]
[('1', '34', 'AM')        (11, 22)             11 hours and 22 minutes in future]
[('3', '48', 'PM')        (1, 36)              1 hours and 36 minutes in future]

Comment: some of the answers are not correct, for example 3rd row I get 13 hours and it has to be 14, also when I have 0 hours it tells me that is now and doesn't take in consideration minutes in the future. Same as for last one and one before

Comment: Well you need to print "now" only when **both** the hours and the minutes are 0. Currently you are printing it when **any** of the two are 0, when `b[0] != 0 and b[1] != 0` is false.

Comment: can you help me please with correct version? nothing comes in my mind now.

Comment: You could start by changing `and` to `or` in the above expression.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to have one function that converts your "time tuple" to "minutes since midnight", then just subtract the two and convert the difference back to hours and minutes.  It's the special cases that are causing your trouble here.

Comment: Your "correct output" is clearly wrong.  From 2:12 PM to 4:03 AM is 13 hours and 51 minutes, as you have.  From 2:12 PM to 1:09 AM is 10 hours and 57 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is way closer than you think.  If you fix the and/or confusion, that will solve the false "Now".  Here is another way to think of the problem, by converting to "minutes since midnight", which eliminated the special cases:

```
tests = """\
2:12 PM
8:23 PM
4:03 AM
1:34 AM
3:48 PM
4:13 AM
1:09 AM
3:12 PM
4:10 PM""".splitlines()

def time_encode(tpl):
    return int(tpl[0]) * 60 + int(tpl[1]) + (0 if tpl[2] == "AM" else 720)

def time_decode(mins):
    return mins//60, mins%60

def time_compare_gen(time_list , target):
    listReturn = []
    tar = time_encode( target )
    for tup in time_list:
        delta = time_encode( tup ) - tar
        if delta < 0:
            delta += 24 * 60
        listReturn.append( time_decode(delta) )
    return listReturn

TimeList = tuple(t.replace(':',' ').split() for t in tests)
tartuple = TimeList[0]
DiffList = time_compare_gen(TimeList,tartuple)
print ("{:<24} {:<20} {:<10}".format('Time Tuple', 'Diffrence', ' '))

for a,b in zip(TimeList , DiffList):
    if b[0] != 0 or b[1] != 0:
        diffstr = str(b[0]) + " hours and " + str(b[1]) + " minutes in future"
    else:
        diffstr = 'Now'
    print ("{:<24} {:<20} {:<10}".format(str(a) , str(b) , diffstr))
```